# analytical solution of a nonlinear differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

can we find a closed form solution -- such as a series solution -- of the following equation

$$\frac{dy_0}{dt}+b\left(\frac{20}{27}y_0(t)^2+\frac{10}{27}y_0(t)-\frac5{81}
y_0(t)^3-\frac4{81}\right) = 0$$

with $y_0(0) = 1$.

thank you

Comment: can you use $\LaTeX$ please?

Comment: It is separable, so you can write $t$ as a function of $y_0$.  This function will be a linear combination of $\log(y_0-r_i)$.  So $t\to\infty$ as $y\to r_i$, where $r_1,r_2$ and $r_3$ are the three roots of the cubic.

Comment: for this equation we can't get a closed form

Answer (score 1):

As commented by Michael, the equation is separable and can write $$\frac{dt}{dy}=-\frac {81}{5b}\times\frac{1}{y^3-12 y^2-6 y+\frac{4}{5}}$$ Using the trigonometric resolution of the cubic, the roots of $y^3-12 y^2-6 y+\frac{4}{5}=0$ are given by $$y1=4+6 \sqrt{2} \cos \left(\frac{1}{3} \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{7}\right)\right)$$ $$y_2=4+3 \sqrt{6} \sin \left(\frac{1}{3} \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{7}\right)\right)-3
   \sqrt{2} \cos \left(\frac{1}{3} \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{7}\right)\right)$$ $$y_3=4-3 \sqrt{6} \sin \left(\frac{1}{3} \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{7}\right)\right)-3
   \sqrt{2} \cos \left(\frac{1}{3} \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{7}\right)\right)$$ That is to say that the equation write $$\frac{dt}{dy}=-\frac {81}{5b}\times\frac 1{(y-y_1)(y-y_2)(y-y_3)}$$ Now, using partial fraction decomposition $$\frac 1{(y-y_1)(y-y_2)(y-y_3)}=\frac{1}{(y_1-y_2) (y_1-y_3)
   (y-y_1)}-\frac{1}{(y_1-y_2) (y_2-y_3) (y-y_2)}-\frac{1}{(y_1-y_3) (y_3-y_2) (y-c)}$$ and integration will give a linear comnination of logarithms (just as Michael aleardy commented).